# How to use AbstractAggregateRoot<T> or the annotation DomainEvents with Java Records

Tags: java, spring-data, domain-driven-design, spring-data-jdbc

I am trying to evolve a domain which it includes and Aggregate-root implemented with Java Records and I am not able to find a way to use the `Domain Event` concept to propagate events from one Aggregate-root.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#core.domain-events

Compilation issue with the following syntax:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;
import org.springframework.data.domain.AbstractAggregateRoot;

@Table("BALANCE")
public record Balance extends AbstractAggregateRoot<Balance> (

    @Id
    @Column("ID_BALANCE")
    Long balanceId,

    @Column("BALANCE")
    BigDecimal balance,

    @Column("ID_CUSTOMER")
    Long customerId,

    @Column("LAST_UPDATE")
    Timestamp lastUpdate,

    @Column("WITHDRAW_LIMIT")
    BigDecimal withdrawLimit
) {
//Business logic
}
```

No problem with this syntax:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;
import org.springframework.data.domain.AbstractAggregateRoot;

public class BalanceDemo extends AbstractAggregateRoot<BalanceDemo> {

    @Id
    @Column("ID_BALANCE")
    Long balanceId;

    @Column("BALANCE")
    BigDecimal balance;

    @Column("ID_CUSTOMER")
    Long customerId;

    @Column("LAST_UPDATE")
    Timestamp lastUpdate;

    @Column("WITHDRAW_LIMIT")
    BigDecimal withdrawLimit;

    //Constructors, Get, HashCode, Equals, toString
    //Business Logic
}
```

What is wrong? Is it not possible to use Java records in combination with `Domain Events`?

Comment: I don't know enough about Spring Data to say whether this is possible in some way, but records cannot extend a class such as `AbstractAggregateRoot`, because they all extend `java.lang.Record`. However, in the documentation linked from the question, the example doesn't extend `AbstractAggregateRoot`, so perhaps there is some way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim Moore wrote in a comment a Java Record cannot extend another class since it already extends `java.lang.Record` implicitly.

So you can either copy the relevant code from [`AbstractAggregateRoot`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/domain/AbstractAggregateRoot.java) into your record or have an instance of it in your record and delegate to it in the relevant method implementations.